# What are the limitations of modelling a piano sound with the 'play' option of the software Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: math-software, mathematical-modeling, wolfram-alpha

'Play' is an input availabe on Wolfram mathematica, which shows how a wave would sound and I am asking myself what the limitations of this input are, in what aspects it does not represent 'real' sound clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Real sound is full of impurities and higher-order effects that are exceptionally hard to model. A piano note is made by striking a wire under tension, causing it to vibrate. But that's not the only thing that generates the sound. The material properties of the piano body, the shape of the cavity, and so on all have a significant effect on the sound.

Real-world "notes" are never pure sinusoids. If you could model the waveform of a real-world instrument very accurately, then Mathematica (or many other software programs) can synthesize the note fairly easily. But the modeling is the hard part.

Comment: The question seems to be asking about the case where [quoting the answer] "you could model the waveform ... very accurately", and whether generation of that waveform on a one-point speaker would 'represent real sound clearly' [to quote the question].  Your answer seems to be that the thing being modeled is complicated, but if you could model it, no problem.  I think the answer is rather that one- or two-point playback is a simplification, though (as we can hear) a reasonable one for many purposes.

Comment: @zyx Those are all very good points. I was more considering the part where the OP asks about the "limitations of this input"... which I understood (perhaps wrongly) to be the limitations in generating waveforms.

Answer (score 0):

A one-dimensional waveform is an accurate model for sound received at one point, all from one direction, with no memory or perceptual effects.  Which is a very simplified model of sound and hearing.